# Simulate smaller screen on a Tablet?

Tags: android, testing, screen

I've developed an app using my Android tablet as a testing tool. I want to test it on smaller screens and I find the emulator damn slow. Is there a way I can configure my tablet to simulate a small screen - perhaps darken everything around and only display a small square?

Like how in Windows we can change the display resolution in the settings screen...asking for too much?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ya it is possible.. if you done your design in the xml layout give the give root tag height and width as fix as your required screen size instead of fillparent

Comment: Do I need to set it in every layout XML ?