# Set screen size for simulation of smaller screen on Android tablet?

Tags: android, simulation

From this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10860347/simulate-smaller-screen-on-a-tablet), I know that it is possible to set the screen size of each layout to simulate smaller screen size on Android tablet. How can I set the "global" screen size across the whole App to simulate a smaller screen size?

I have a Sony Xperia Z Tablet (10"), and would like to simulate 7" tablet with resolution 768 x 1024.

Comment: your best bet is to use an AVD

Comment: AVD cannot test certain hardware feature such as BLE , NFC , etc.